# How to use Oracle Grid Control management repository view to check if the "block change tracking" enabled on all dbs?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, gridcontrol

I couldn't find a Oracle Grid Control management repository view to check if "block change tracking" enabled for all Oracle 11g databases being monitored by GC 11g.  I know I can query the v$block_change_tracking on an Oracle database, but there are 100+ Oracle 11g databases in my environment, I hope I could pull this information from a view like MGMT$DB_INIT_PARAMS, which doesn't contain such information.  I searched Oracle doc: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b16246/views.htm#BACDADEJ, but found nothing.  Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not a initialization parameter you won't find it in the view MGMT$DB_INIT_PARAMS.

You have to query the view V$BLOCK_CHANGE_TRACKING:

```
select STATUS from V$BLOCK_CHANGE_TRACKING;
```

In GridControl there is a page where you can execute a SQL statement on all configured/selected targets and view the result in a table. I can't recall where exactly that page is because I used it only once and all my GridControl servers are already migrated to CloudControl.

But perhaps you can find it with this information.

Comment: Thanks. I remember this option. I thought I could it by querying a mgmt$ view so that I can schedule a report to run it periodically.

Comment: No, Oracle does not monitor it out of the box. You could write a manual monitor which checks the status of v$block_change_tracking.